# WebView not working

Tags: android, url, webview

i want to disable phone browser and i want to use  a webview . 
but this code didn't work for me . please guide me :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Wop=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webi);

        String mturl="http://www.google.com";
        Wop.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        Wop.loadUrl(mturl);
        }
```

Comment: But do you mean "didn't work"? Are u getting some error message? Post your logcat

Comment: i mean this code didn't work in my programm

Comment: follow this simple example first: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/ see how web view works

Comment: After that you can follow the below code/answer if want your customized webview. More specificly you have to override this method of your customized web view: shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url);{ view.loadUrl(url);
            return true; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
            mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
            mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
```

To enable the **previous** web-page to be loaded,

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        } }
```

Definiton of the **`HelloWebViewClient`** class :

```
private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);


            //what you want to do when the page finished loading, eg. give some message, show progress bar, etc
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

            //what you want to do when the page starts loading, eg. give some message
        }


    }
```

Comment: Sure: Don't post generic code to answer unclear questions. Ask for clarification instead. This is not an answer to a specific issue and rewards unclear, low-quality questions. They keep getting posted, thanks to answers like this one because people have no reason to put more effort into them.

Comment: Hey! I was just trying to help the guy out! And since I had no idea what his exact problem was, I gave all the possible solutions and customizations. So I get downvoted for helping out **Too** much ? Isn't that unfair sir ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure these are not "all the possible solutions". Also: This is not "helping too much". It's helping less. Why? This question is now useless to all the search engine users who find it. Had you clarified the question instead and answered specific, it would be way more helpful to many more people (who potentially have the same issue). Generic webview code is not helpful, you can find thousands of examples just like this via google. All you did was reward OPs laziness. So, no, not unfair in my eyes.

Comment: Oh, okay. I get your point now. Just been a few months on SO, still learning a few things around here. Will keep that in mind for later issues. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
WebView w = new WebView(this);
```

//add this to your code

```
 w.setWebViewClient(new Callback());
 w.loadUrl("http://www.facebook.com");
```

//and this class also

```
private class Callback extends WebViewClient{  //HERE IS THE MAIN CHANGE. 

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return (false);
            }

        }
```